# How to redirect to a site from proxy java

Tags: java, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

Am using Apache Httpclient to open a URL through proxy and getting response instead I want to redirect the site from a proxy passing post parameters.
This is my code , It is a servlet

```
        String parameter= request.getParameter("parameter");
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(); 


        httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(proxyhost, proxyport);  
        log.info("message:::"+message);
        PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(url);  
        NameValuePair[] data = new NameValuePair[1];  
        data[0] = new NameValuePair("parameter", parameter); 
        postMethod.setRequestBody(data);  

        int code = httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod); 
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.print(postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());
```

Actual problem is am getting response from other site and html is being rendered and clicking the link in browser the URL is being opened from my server because the response is coming this this format
var url "../../someparams" 
It should indeed open  http://url/someparams(url here is mentioned above one in the code) or The as soon as the URL is hit using proxy can we redirect to that page in the browser too I mean opening the URL through that proxy and removing the URl of the servlet being called.

@Law Anthony:
response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com"); is not helping

Need your help to resolve this .

Comment: How it can't solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a servlet?
If it is,

```
repsonse.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
```

This will send a code 302 redirect to the request.

EDIT: What exactly you want?